# Grails 3.3.10 and strange behavior in the URLs

Tags: grails, grails3

I'm developing an application using `Grails 3.3.10` using `Spring security plugin` but I'm getting very weird behavior, when I run the application using `-https` for instance I finished editing the `Profile` in the `edit.gsp` here its URL `https://localhost:8443/profile/edit/1` and I press `Update` so it will suppose to take me to the `index.gsp` but the URL I get is `http://localhost:8080//profile/index` as you can see the URL isn't `https` and there is extra `/` by the way this is happing in a lot of the views.
What is the reason for this behavior

Comment: Hard to answer without details about your grails config and your gsp.  This link may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @npskirk , i don't know what exactly to share is it the `domain` or the `view` pages  or the `Spring security configs`

Comment: I don't know how to say it any better than it is already stated in the "how to ask" tip sheet, and one of its sections -- https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what is the cause for this weird behavior i found in config file `application.yml`, the property `grails.serverURL` was configured twice ,so i commented them and everything worked fine